# PHP inserting Suggestion into SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I don't know what is wrong, there are currently no errors when going to my suggestion page so I don't know what is wrong, got any ideas?

```
//index.php

<form name="suggestion" action="http://example.com/suggestions.php" method="POST">
<font style="font-family: arial; color:#3f3f3f; font-size:15px;">Provide me with a URL to one or multiple songs that you want on the website!</font> <br><br><input style="width:243px;" type="text" name="suggestion"><br>
<br>
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>


//suggestions.php

<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "u611142741_list", "[REDACTED]"); 
 mysql_select_db("u611142741_sugge", $conn);

// If the form has been submitted

$suggestion = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['suggestion']);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];



    // Build an sql statment to add the student details
    $sql="INSERT INTO suggestions

(Suggestion,IP Address) VALUES

('$suggestion','$ip')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);


// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Is your field name really "IP Address" with a space?

Comment: Indeed. "IP Address"

Answer (score 0):

Your field name has a space in it, and it needs to be quoted. What you have now is;

```
INSERT INTO suggestions (Suggestion,IP Address) VALUES ('$suggestion','$ip')
```

...but the field name `IP Address` contains a space and needs to be quoted, normally in MySQL using backticks, resulting in;

```
INSERT INTO suggestions (Suggestion, `IP Address`) VALUES ('$suggestion','$ip')
```

Comment: Okay, now the attributes appear in my sql table, but the suggestion is blank, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @user4191887 Could it be that your entire form is named the same thing as your text field?

Comment: Errm.. i've changed the form's name to "suggestions" but it still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO suggestions

(`Suggestion`,`IP Address`) VALUES

('$suggestion','$ip')";
```

Let me know if works.